# popBackStackImmediate() seems not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

### Quick Overview

I have a single `Activity`, with multiple `Fragments`.

In one fragment (A), I call another one (B), when I'm done I click a button on this fragment (B) and I get back to the other one (A).

The issue is, in this fragment (A) I have buttons, but when I click 'em again when I'm back from fragment (B), they don't work.

Rather, they execute a function in fragment (B) even though we're in fragment (A).

---

### onClick() method in Fragment (A):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.nextMessage:
            System.out.println("NextMessage - Start");
            game();
            System.out.println("NextMessage - End");
            break;
        case R.id.playersList:
            System.out.println("PlayersList - Start");
            lookUpPlayers();
            System.out.println("PlayersList - End");
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
}
```

---

### onClick() method in Fragment (B):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.backToGame:
            provider.getFragmentSwitcher().back();
            System.out.println("Back executed.");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Default executed.");
            break;
    }
    }
```

---

When I come back to Fragment (A) from (B), all the buttons in (A) execute the default value of the witcher in (B)!
So the output is:"Default executed." .

Why is that?

---

This is the back() method instead:

```
public void back(){
    fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
}
```

---

### Question

What is the reason of this.. weird issue? Why does the Fragment A execute a method in Fragment B?

---

### Resources

If you want to give it either a run or a look, here's the [GitHub](https://github.com/SnipCode/Lupus_New) project!

Comment: Possibility of an Instant Run bug?

Comment: I wiped the data of the virtual device, and started as new the App, each time @Shaishav

Answer (score 1):

I have just built test application for you.
I will share it here.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

MainAcitivty.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragmentA)
                .commit();
```

}
}

layout_fragment_a.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_mainLayout"
    tools:context="com.nikolay.fragmentmanagertest.FragmentA">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="FragmentA"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

FragmentA.java

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    private Button nextBtn;
    public FragmentA() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_a, container, false);
        nextBtn = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.next_btn);
        nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
                getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_mainLayout, fragmentB).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

layout_fragment_b.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_mainLayout"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    tools:context="com.nikolay.fragmentmanagertest.FragmentB">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="FragmentB"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Back"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

FragmentB.java

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    private Button backButton;

    public FragmentB() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_b, container, false);
        backButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.back_btn);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getParentFragment().getChildFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I have tested this code on my side. I think it works well as you wish.

Please try with this and then let me know the result.
I hope this will be good for you.

Nikolay